# How to draw a line on chart?

Tags: java, charts, line, jfreechart, draw

The problem is, how to make simplier and more effective. 
I'm using jfreechart, and I want to draw a line from one point to another by clicking a mouse.
I have overrided chartMouseClicked to set start point and, after next click end point of line.
It works. But want to see my line, with beginning on start point, and the end on mouse cursor, while, after first click, I'm moving cursor. I've done it by setting dataset and setting renderer in my overrided chartMouseMoved method, but it is creating many datasets after every move of cursor. My question is how to make visible preview of the line which I'm making by 2xclick of mouse.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let jFreechart render into an off-screen image and use that image to draw your widget's background. Then, you don't need to worry about jFreechart's internals and event handling; you can use the standard Swing/AWT approach to create a simple vector graphics editor.

Comment: Yes, but problem is, that is a dynamic chart, which is updating after every minute, and, this line is something like trend line. It is linked to some values of chart. How to solve it?

Comment: In that case, you will have to find a way to make the code of your mouse move handler efficient because there is no way to limit the number of events. I suggest to cache as many values as possible and flush the caches when the chart is updated.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to render line without storing data in dataset? Or, just better is make this over the chart, with some standard library to draw, for example on jpanel which handle chartpanel?

Comment: I don't know the internals of jFreeChart; maybe look into the source code how it repaints itself.